# In dplyr 1.0.0, what is the right way to write a logical disjunction?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently in the process of tiding the way in write my R scripts, so I am not really looking for an answer outside the tidyverse or using deprecated / superseded syntaxes. I find dplyr's way of manipulating data easy to write and read, so I try to stick to it.

Using the iris dataset, here is a simplified version of what I want to do, in the superseded syntax (which works fine):

```
filter_at(iris, vars(starts_with("sepal")), any_vars(. > 3))
```

Obviously, I could write the condition in the long form to avoid using `filter_at()` and `any_vars()` :

```
filter(iris, Sepal.Length > 3 | Sepal.Width > 3)
```

but it is redundant, and mostly, if like in my case the column names are not known fully, not applicable.

In dplyr's [vignette("colwise")](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html), it is stated:

> *Previously, filter() was paired with the all_vars() and any_vars() helpers. Now, across() is equivalent to all_vars(), and there’s no direct replacement for any_vars(). However you can make a simple helper yourself:*

followed by a super trivial example (any value > 0, so we only need using `rowSums()`). I feel like it's lacking a disjunctive version of `across()` in the specific case of filtering to maintain the same expressivity.

In your opinion, what would be the cleanest syntax to achieve the same filtering without having to enumerate all the columns or to use superseded functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `across` with `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
iris %>% 
    filter(across(starts_with("sepal"), ~ . > 5) %>% reduce(`|`))
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#2            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#3            5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#4            5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#5            5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#6            5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa
#7            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what you suggest will return a row if **all** values (in the selected columns) are > 3, while I am looking for a way to select a row if **any** value is > 3.

Comment: @marika I did updated the post.  Please check.  If you check my condition, to make it more explicity,  I used `> 5`.

Comment: Many thanks! I love this syntax and it works! Now I have got some digging to do to clearly understand how/why it works though.

Comment: @marika. `reduce` with `|` or `&` does the `any`, `all`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? Here we include any rows where either Sepal.Length *or* Sepal.Width is greater than 3.

`c_across` takes the specified columns and treats each row of those variables as a vector, iterating one row at a time. So, you can perform rowwise filtering by checking if any of the specified columns in the row are greater than 3.

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(c_across(starts_with("sepal")) > 5))
#> # A tibble: 118 x 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  3          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          5.8         4            1.2         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa 
#>  9          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa 
#> 10          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2 setosa 
#> # … with 108 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If you change 3 to 5 then this code should remove row 2, but it will not. `any` does not work row-wise. Change `filter` to `summarise` and you will see the output inside `filter` is just a single `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this returns all rows. My example did return all row too, though, because I poorly chose the threshold. It becomes more evident if using 5 as in the accepted answer. My bad.

Comment: @marika @IceCreamToucan thanks for pointing that out - adding `rowwise` grouping fixes the issue.

Comment: @RyanFrost thanks for this other way! I had tried to use rowwise() and c_across(), but I could not find the right way to achieve what I wanted; now I do :)